# Joining two tables based on Case statement

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have two tables. I want to join them on the same column but the values used to join them are different.

e.g select * from 
table A join table B
on A.name=B.name

but in my case A.name and B.name are not the same A.name='apple' should join to every row in B where B.name='apple' or B.name='orange'. Is this possible using Case statement or anyother way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible using Case statement ...?

Below is simplified / dummy example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.tableA` AS (
  SELECT 1 colsA, 'apple' name union all
  SELECT 2, 'lemon' union all
  SELECT 3, 'peach'
), `project.dataset.tableB` AS (
  SELECT 4 colsB, 'apple' name union all
  SELECT 5, 'orange' union all
  SELECT 6, 'melon'
)
SELECT 
  a.name AS a_name,
  b.name AS b_name,
  colsA,
  colsB
FROM `project.dataset.tableA` a
JOIN `project.dataset.tableB` b
ON CASE 
    WHEN a.name = 'apple' AND b.name IN ('apple', 'orange') THEN TRUE
    WHEN a.name = 'peach' AND b.name IN ('peach', 'melon') THEN TRUE
  END
```

with the output :

```
Row a_name  b_name  colsA   colsB    
1   apple   apple   1       4    
2   apple   orange  1       5    
3   peach   melon   3       6
```

> ... or any other way?

Even simplified version of above is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  a.name AS a_name,
  b.name AS b_name,
  colsA,
  colsB
FROM `project.dataset.tableA` a
JOIN `project.dataset.tableB` b
ON (a.name = 'apple' AND b.name IN ('apple', 'orange'))
OR (a.name = 'peach' AND b.name IN ('peach', 'melon'))
```

obviously with same output

Answer (score 1):

You can use more complicated logic on the `on` clause:

```
from a join
     b
     on a.name = 'apple and b.name in ('apple', 'orange')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can make similar WHEN conditions if you have more combinations in B table  
that you would like to join like apple and orange. However if it's only apple 
and orange then this can be done using below.
```

```
SELECT A.*,B.* 
FROM tbl_A A 
JOIN tbl_B B on A.name = CASE WHEN B.Name in ('Apple','Orange')
                              THEN 'Apple'
                              ELSE B.Name
                              END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
SELECT * FROM A a
    INNER JOIN B b ON a.name = 'Apple' AND b.name IN ('Apple', 'Orange')
```